# Updating Title as a Clock using Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create a time keeper on a GUI that essentially shows the time, but updates the time every second. Do you know how to use Python to update the time using a GUI? I am using the Kv GUI.

I wanted to make it a button with the time on it possibly as a text changing on the button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html). You will use it like `Clock.schedule_interval(update_time, 1)` to update the time every second. You can update it even more often if you'd like (like every 0.1 seconds, for example).